# Using wp_insert_post() - creates duplicates

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I am adding one CPT to another CPT dynmaically. When using `wp_insert_post()` it creates duplicates when I `add_action('init', 'function_name');` Any idea what hook to use to simply add them:

```
function cpt_to_cpt(){    
// Grab posts
    $args =  array(
        'post_type'     => ' custom_type1 ',
        'order'         =>  'ASC',
        'post_status'   =>  'publish',
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        );

    $posts = get_posts($args);

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {  
        wp_insert_post(array(
            'post_type'     =>  'custom_type2',
            'post_title'    =>  $post->post_title,
            'post_date'     =>  $post->post_date,
            'post_author'   =>  $post->post->author,
            'post_status'   =>  'publish',
            )
         );
      }
add_action('init', 'cpt_to_cpt');
```

Comment: If you're doing this for a project, you could use a plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

[`wp_loaded`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_loaded)

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'cpt_to_cpt');
```

or

[`wp`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp)

```
add_action('wp', 'cpt_to_cpt')
```

Comment: using `add_action('wp', 'cpt_to_cpt')` thanks. Modified the code using a condition: `if ( !get_page_by_title($post->post_title, OBJECT, 'custom_type2') )`

Answer (score 0):

WordPress [`init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/init/) and [`wp_loaded`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_loaded/) hooks fire on the "loading" stage. It means they both can fire more than one time when refreshing the page.

**Solution 1**

You can use another hook that fires later.

[`wp`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp/) hook, for instance, fires on the "processing" stage and should run only once.

```
add_action('wp', 'cpt_to_cpt');
```

Order of precedence: `init`  `wp_loaded`  `wp`

**Solution 2**

If you really want to use `init` hook and make sure it will run one time. You can use the snippet below.

```
function cpt_to_cpt() {
    $runtime = 'run_only_01;
    if (get_option('my_run_only_once_option') != $runtime) {
        $updated = update_option('my_run_only_once_option', $runtime);
        if ($updated === true) {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'cpt_to_cpt');
```

It will create an option on your `wp_option` table. In the end, you need to delete the option manually (on your database) or in your code.

```
delete_option('my_run_only_once_option');
```

**Solution 3**

Maybe the best professional solution to create multiple posts or CPTs (custom post types) should be using [`wp-cli`](https://wp-cli.org/) (command line interface for WordPress).

Please take a look in the documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/post/